# Getting HTTP 401 with Spring Boot custom authorization server when accessing spring client

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-security

Hi everyone i am not able to proceed with following settings. your small pointers are appreciated.

**problem statement**
i am trying to use custom authorization server provided by spring cloud security and OAuth2 with my web application so that it can propagate access token to micro services in back end.

i can able to see my authorization server can able to provide access token and when try to ingest access token for invoking endpoints for for back end micro service it work as per expectation

problem faced
when i provide following configuration in spring boot web client(which will call my back end micro service)

**in application.properties**

```
security.oauth2.client.clientId=myclient
security.oauth2.client.clientSecret=abcsecret
security.oauth2.client.access-token-uri=http://localhost:9000/services/oauth/token
security.oauth2.client.user-authorization-uri=http://localhost:9000/services/oauth/authorize
security.oauth2.client.clientAuthenticationScheme=form
security.oauth2.resource.user-info-uri=http://localhost:9000/services/user
security.oauth2.resource.prefer-token-info=true
```

and i provide

```
http://localhost:8080
```

in my browser. it asks for credentials. i provide credentials as present with authorization server.
once valid credentials provided authorization server asks for valid scopes.

but **one important thing** i observe when my web client routed to authorization server it has **redirect_uri**

```
 http://localhost:8080/login
```

(not ok since initially i entered http://localhost:8080)
**i am also getting HTTP 401 error**